# Getting text from Text Box Cross class returns null

Tags: c#, .net

So the title explains itself, when I try too access the text box through classes it returns null.. Even when there is text in the box at the time.

This is the code used in the class with the Text Box

```
private static string InputText;
public string GetText()
    {
        InputText = TextBox.Text;
        return InputText;
    }
```

This is the code I use in the other class too call the function and use it...

```
public static SafeText.Form1 Form1;
EncData = Crypto256.Encrypt(Form1.GetText(), Key);
```

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Have you initialised your Form1 variable?  You haven't provided any code to show that you have.

Comment: You are presumably getting a `NullReferenceException` at the last line, but not because `Text` is null, it's because `Form1` is probably unassigned.

Comment: So what is the actual problem here? I find it *highly* unlikely that `GetText()` returns `null` since `TextBox.Text` (assuming this is a normal WinForms textbox) doesn't do that. Is the problem a `NullReferenceException` because `Form1` isn't assigned?

Comment: By what do you mean assigning Form1?